# KNET Payment Gateway Integration in Android

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I want to integrate KNet Payment gateway in one of my Android application, but I did not find any API documentation or sample code for integration. Can anyone suggest me where can I get this or any resource link where I can explore to get it. If any one have done before then please share the information, it will really help me lot. I appreciate for the help.

Thanks

Comment: Did You Set uped the Payment Gateway For Website?

Comment: @Ashish have you found any soluition

Comment: @Ashish, Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I think Knet has no support for Android. Currently it only supports Php and Asp. Better you should integrate a site which uses Knet. Then use a webview in android and call that site. I will work. I have already done.

Comment: Knet, I want to implement in my ios App. so, no any ThirdParty Library or no any Code For that ? Only Open in Webview ? Which Link Open in webview ?So,Plz Give me some Proper Way...

Comment: @Raju did you find the solution for knet

Comment: Dears, Did find the solution ?

Comment: how to get response from knet ie. suceess or failure ?

Answer (score 1):

using MyFatoorah Apis, which is the easiest way to accept Knet, credit cards, and many other MyFatoorah payment methods. 
this is the sample sdk code for both kotlin and java 
https://dev.azure.com/myfatoorahsc/_git/MF-SDK-Android-Demo

Comment: Any library/apis like MyFatoorah for iOS?